# Android 4.4.2 - How to not dismiss notification while checking the detail

Tags: notifications, 4.4-kitkat, calendar

I recently upgraded my phone to Galaxy S5. This phone has 4.4.2. One big inconvenience I have encountered so far is the way the event and notification work - the system automatically dismisses a notification when I tap on the notification to check the detail. Usually, I can only prioritize what I am doing and the upcoming events after seeing the event detail. But by tapping on the notification, the notification is dismissed and will not show up later, should I decide to ignore the notification for now.

Previously on 4.0, unless I mark a notification and tap on a dismiss button, the notification stays. I would like to keep the old behavior if possible.

Answer (score 3):

It's up to the app (developer) to set when the notification is dismissed (automatically when you touch it, or at some other time), so it sounds like the difference here isn't between the two Android versions, but between the calendar app you were using on your old phone, and the one on your new phone.

Because it's up to the app, it means you just need to find a calendar app where the event notifications behave the way you want (or where there's an option to control it).

Comment: I am using the calendar coming with both phones. I have tried digging through settings but couldn't find a way to change it.